# How can I fix this error that PyCharm is giving me on Python 3.8

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kids/Library/Mail/V5/E60CBF1C-9021-4A10-8D60-06C96C141AF1/Outbox.mbox/E7C72E99-E3DB-4CDC-B1C9-15116F3478D8/Data/Attachments/405/2/ASL-Finger-Spelling-Recognition-master/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution3D, MaxPooling3D
  File "/Users/kids/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Users/kids/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .keras import np_utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.keras'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace and the code you are running? Right now no error is shown

Comment: Ok I edited it.

Comment: it doesn't show anything other than `exit code 1`? No other exception details?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Is this just failing at an import statement that you are running?

Comment: Because when I run `from keras.utils import keras` I get a similar stacktrace. Running `from keras import utils; dir(utils)` I don't see that it has a `keras` attribute

Comment: make sure you're import is this `import keras_utils`

Comment: Do import it in my code? Or the terminal?

Comment: It seems your keras is not visible within PyCharm. Have you picked a right python interpreted in PyCharm? I see that you use a virtual environment, so you have to adjust your interpreter accordingly. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: In fact, yes I have. I have python 3.8 as an interpreter on PyCharm. Im not sure if that would help but do you recommend changing it to the most latest or and older version?

Comment: Please install keras package in `PyCharm terminal` using `pip install <>` and see if it works